# How should I animate a Circle/Soap-Bubble in iOS (possibly with Swift)?

Tags: ios, animation, sprite-kit, core-graphics

I'm not an expert on animations and drawing, so I'm trying to validate the most efficient way to solve this problem. 
I need to create a Soap Bubble-Like Circle view; it should look like a soap bubble that floats in the air, for now I'm just concerned on the shape and not the position on screen, which is assumed to be fixed.

The end result should be a Circle that gets deformed at specific points along the circumference (as a soap bubble would look when it floats in the air).

I've been thinking of these possible solutions:

- Explore the particle effects available in SpriteKit to find some ready-made effect.
- Use UIBezierPath to draw a deformed circle with some function and animate it.

Since both of the things require some degree of deepening, I'd like to know which one in your opinion would be the best solution to do the job, some examples or tutorials would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If I've understand your question, you want to realize something similar to  the "soap bubbles". I think the fastest way was to make `SKShapeNode` with some animation to change  it's path during the time but you don't have the sensation to see a bubble deformation..and in my honest opinion this result is ugly. Another ugly situation can be obtain with `SKFieldNode`.

You can also constraining a node(with `SKConstraint`) to obtain some deformation but it's hard to calculate everytime a reasonable distortion especially because you should have to do with more than one constraint..

I think that the best result could be obtained with `SKWarpGeometryGrid` that allows you to deform sprites (**iOS 10**).

[image]

I think that if you follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37884312/1894067) example to understand how to prepare your grid, you can build your control points array  and define a warp geometry to have a good "soap bubble" simulation.

I hope this helps for your research.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I'll give a try to the link you've provided and let you know, but I think it gets really close to what I'm looking for.
I've also edited my question because a soap bubble is a much more precise way to "give the idea" ;)

Answer (score 0):

in viewDidLoad:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.2, target: self, selector: #selector(makeBubble), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

and add a function in your viewController:

```
@objc func makeBubble() {
    let bubbleImage = UIImage(systemName: "circle")
    let bubbleImageView = UIImageView(image: bubbleImage)
    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let bubbleWidth = Int(bubbleImage!.size.width)
    let bubbleHeight = Int(bubbleImage!.size.height)
    let randomX = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(screenSize.width))
    bubbleImageView.frame = CGRect(x: Int(randomX) - Int(Double(bubbleWidth) * 0.5), y: Int(screenSize.height) + bubbleHeight, width: bubbleWidth, height: bubbleHeight)
    view.addSubview(bubbleImageView)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 7.0, animations: {
        bubbleImageView.center = CGPoint(x: bubbleImageView.center.x, y: CGFloat(-bubbleHeight))
    }) { (finished: Bool) in
        bubbleImageView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}
```